# Microsoft Teams graph api (get channels) does not return data in users default language it always returns data in english?

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have my teams client language setup in french, I see the general channel name change in french,
however when I use GRAPH REST API GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id} to query the channels for the logged in user it returns data to me in english and not french

does the API support language selected by the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Microsoft Teams graph api does not support the function of language translation. This is because when you created the teams, it was already stored in the database in the default language (English), so when you call the API, you get it from the database The data is displayed in English, and Microsoft Teams graph api cannot translate it for you in real time.

Although the customer language of your team is set to French, this is only the language displayed on the page, and the data storage language of the back-end database is still the default English.

Comment: How does teams client then support multi lingual? when i go to teams client as a french user it does show me the data in french

Comment: @Riddhi The French or any non-English display on the portal is probably a translation made by calling other APIs, which does not change the data existing in the database at all.

Comment: so when i use API to query a list the list metadata comes in french language from the API as the user selected language is set to french, however same with teams API does not work. not sure if there is a way in other APIs also to return data in english only that way it would be consistent